# How to get IColorManager and IPreferenceStore of Eclipse XML editor?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I want to use IColorManager and IPreferenceStore of Eclipse internal XML editor in my XML viewer. I spent whole day but could not find the relevant classes/methods.
Please help me to get out of this trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usin the plug-in spy (alt + shift + F1) I found that the preference page used is "XMLSyntaxColoringPage". provided by the "org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui" plug-in.

Starting from there you could try to figure out how to get the data you need :)

Comment: Thank you @cerealk for your help but probably due to different version of eclipse (3.6) I could not find XMLSyntaxColoringPage class in org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui package. However there is a class org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.preferences.XMLSyntaxColoringPage that may serve the purpose but it is internal and not recommended for our use. Could you give me some other hint to put me back on track?